# simple-peer package doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, webrtc

I am trying to use [simple-peer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer) package in my Meteor application to implement voice chat.

Here is how I am using the package:

```
'click #btnCall ': function(e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var Peer = require('simple-peer');

        var p = new Peer({ initiator: location.hash === '#1', trickle: false });

        p.on('signal', function(data) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    }
```

From the code above, when I click "btnCall" button, the metada of the current user should be printed to the console but instead, I get the following error:

> Could not complete the operation due to error c004e001

I tried to look online but couldn't find any with similar issue on simple-peer

Any feedback on what is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c004e001 is an ORTC error code so it looks like you're using Microsoft Edge. Typically it means that one of the STUN/TURN servers is in a format Edge does not like.